# Circular flow diagram with labels

Tags: tikz-arrows, labels

The code snippet is from Zarko's code from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628665/circular-flow-diagram-with-arrows). I am additionally looking for labelled arrows, however the labels appear exactly on arrow, is there a way to make them outside the circle?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               backgrounds,
               fit,
               matrix,
               positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{block2/.style={rectangle, draw=gray,rounded corners, line width=.9mm,text width=26mm, fill=gray!50,text centered, 
minimum height=4em}, line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=20mm, sibling distance=30mm},
level 2/.style={level distance=20mm, rounded corners, sibling distance=15mm},
level 3/.style={level distance=20mm, rounded corners,},
myarrow/.style=
    {draw=gray,line width=3pt,-stealth,rounded corners
    },}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4ex and 0em,
every edge/.style = {draw=gray,line width=3pt , -stealth,rounded corners, bend angle=20},
                    ]
    \node [block2] (1) {A};
    \node [block2, below right= of 1] (2) {B};
 
    \node [block2, below left= of 2] (3) {C};
     
    \node [block2, above left= of 3] (4) {D};
     
\path   (1.east) edge [bend left] node {some label}  (2);
\path         (2) edge [bend left] node {some more label }  (3.east);
\path         (3.west) edge [bend left] node {some even more label}  (4);
\path         (4) edge [bend left]  (1.west);       
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For labels use `quotes` library, to its style definition add option `auto`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                matrix,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5ex and 0em,
     block/.style = {draw=gray, rounded corners, line width=.9mm,
                    fill=gray!30, outer sep=0pt,
                    minimum height=4em, text width=22mm, align=center},
every edge/.style = {-Stealth, draw=gray, line width=3pt, bend left=24},
every edge quotes/.style= {auto, font=\small, align=center}
                    ]
\node [block] (1) {A};
\node [block, below right= of 1] (2) {B};
\node [block, below  left= of 2] (3) {C};
\node [block, above  left= of 3] (4) {D};

\path   (1.east) edge ["some label"]  (2)
        (2)      edge ["some more label"]  (3.east)
        (3.west) edge ["some even\\ more label"]  (4)
        (4)      edge   (1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: selected this answer for simplicity of `auto`

Answer (score 2):

Just add anchors to your nodes (and a small inner sep to them).

[image: circular flow diagram]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
               backgrounds,
               fit,
               matrix,
               positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{block2/.style={rectangle, draw=gray,rounded corners, line width=.9mm,text width=26mm, fill=gray!50,text centered, 
minimum height=4em}, line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=20mm, sibling distance=30mm},
level 2/.style={level distance=20mm, rounded corners, sibling distance=15mm},
level 3/.style={level distance=20mm, rounded corners,},
myarrow/.style=
    {draw=gray,line width=3pt,-stealth,rounded corners
    },
lbl/.style={inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4ex and 0em,
every edge/.style = {draw=gray,line width=3pt , -stealth,rounded corners, bend angle=20},
                    ]
    \node [block2] (1) {A};
    \node [block2, below right= of 1] (2) {B};
 
    \node [block2, below left= of 2] (3) {C};
     
    \node [block2, above left= of 3] (4) {D};
     
\path   (1.east) edge [bend left] node[lbl,above right] {some label}  (2);
\path         (2) edge [bend left] node[lbl,below right] {some more label }  (3.east);
\path         (3.west) edge [bend left] node[lbl,below left] {some even more label}  (4);
\path         (4) edge [bend left]  (1.west);       
    \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: upvoted for neat solution